# How to add new slave server to existing Mysql master slave replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mysql-replication

I have a Mysql Master server and Slave replication on Amazon Ec2 instance.
Currently need to add new slave server to this loop. I can take AMI of existing slave server and spin new slave server.

> How to add new slave server to existing slave server with out making any changes to Master server.
>
> How to configure new slave server writeable like accept new tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps here - https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/howtos/setting_up_replication.html#adding-more-slaves-to-the-master

Regarding: how to configure new slave server writable. I hope you mean only receive replication events from the master. As much as possible you don't want the slave to be writable to avoid data inconsistencies unless you really know what you're doing :)

Comment: I agree, but here I need to add some extra tables (not existing on master, with different prefix) for performing some data monitoring.

Comment: @adminz then slave should be writable just make sure read-only is not ON and your users have the rights :)